# Creating Dynamic Components Angular Cli

Tags: javascript, angular, dynamic, components, angular-cli

I want to create Dynamic components and previously when i was working with Angular 2, I used this piece of code from another stack-overflow answer which worked fine until i switched to Angular-cli. How can i make it work in angular cli?

```
import {
  Component,
  Directive,
  NgModule,
  Input,
  ViewContainerRef,
  Compiler
} from '@angular/core';

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Directive({
  selector: 'html-outlet' 
})
export class HtmlOutlet {
  @Input() html: string;

  constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private compiler: Compiler) {}


  ngOnChanges() {

    const html = this.html;
    if (!html) return;

    @Component({
      selector: 'dynamic-comp',
      templateUrl: html
    })
    class DynamicHtmlComponent  { };

    @NgModule({
      imports: [CommonModule],
      declarations: [DynamicHtmlComponent]
    })
    class DynamicHtmlModule {}

    this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(DynamicHtmlModule)
      .then(factory => {
        const compFactory = factory.componentFactories.find(x => x.componentType === DynamicHtmlComponent);
        this.vcRef.clear();
        const cmpRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(compFactory, 0);
      });
  }
}
```